# Error - "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python " "datetime and date objects as input."

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I tried to declared a variable contains of Datetime like this

```
ts1.departure_date = '2012-03-03 10:10:10'
```

but then I got this error

```
StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
```

I wonder what is the correct way to declare a variable with datetime format? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried: `ts1.departure_date = datetime(2012,3,3,10,10,10)` ?

Comment: @Joe Clements: write that as answer, will upvote

Comment: @JonClements I tried like what you said and import datetime but then I got this error  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, any thoughts? thanks

Comment: @wiko: `datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10)` then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First import the `datetime` class:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then create a `datetime` object and use that to set your attribute:

```
ts1.departure_date = datetime(2012, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    expiration_year  = int(form.expiration_date.data[:4])
    expiration_month =  int(form.expiration_date.data[5:7])
    expiration_date = int(form.expiration_date.data[8:10])
    expiration_date =datetime(expiration_year,expiration_month,expiration_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultra strange error that encountered with SQLAlchemy with both SQLite and Postgres

```
from datetime import datetime

....
#WORKS
 lending_operation = models.LendingOperation(

                device_id = device.device_id,
                start_using = datetime.now()
            )
        db.session.add(lending_operation)
        db.session.commit()

#DIDN'T WORK

lending_operation = models.LendingOperation(
                currency = "USD",
                device_id = device.device_id,
                start_using = datetime.now()
            )
        db.session.add(lending_operation)
        db.session.commit()

#MODEL: models.py
class LendingOperation(db.Model):
    .....
    start_using = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now )
    .....
    currency = db.Column(db.DateTime)

Hope it helps, didn't find any info on the exception
```

Comment: Your model defines `currency` as a DataTime type. It wouldn't work if you try to add `currency = 'USD'` where `USD` is a string, would it?