# Insert into sqlalchelmy date field

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The User has enters the date into an input.

```
print form.date.data
>>> '2017-03-05'
```

now i want to enter the the date or into this

```
expiration_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

the error i get is

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError



  StatementError: <unprintable StatementError object>


raise TypeError("SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
```

What can i do to get rid of convert it to the right format or fix the error.

Comment: check this : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344237/error-sqlite-datetime-type-only-accepts-python-datetime-and-date-objects-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.date.data` is a string it should be converted to python datetime because sqlalchemy `DateTime` column is a python datetime. Or you can store date as a string. To convert it:

```
import datetime
y, m, d = form.date.data.split('-')
expiration_date = datetime.datetime(int(y), int(m), int(d))
```

Comment: expiration_date = datetime(int(form.expiration_date.data)) then i get this error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-03-28'  i think i will just prase into year date month and then use datetime function

Comment: Yeah I forgot about it. You can split string. I updated answer