# How To Fix DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input in python?

Tags: python, datetime, flask

I'm creating a blog in Flask but I'm getting an issue while creating blog posts. I always get this error:

```
SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
```

It's showing the error as coming from my models.py file.

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50),)
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y")))
    description = db.Column(db.Text,)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self,title,description,user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.user_id = user_id
```

Comment: You try to parse a string into a Datetime object. Create a real datetime object, example: datetime(2012, 3, 3, 10, 10, 10).
[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344237/error-sqlite-datetime-type-only-accepts-python-datetime-and-date-objects-a)

Answer (score 1):

The datetime object should not be converted to a string. It should be:

```
time = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=(datetime.datetime.now))
```

Comment: actually you should not pass the function result, but rather the function reference: `default=datetime.datetime.now`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer` type rather than DateTime in the model column declaration.

`time = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False,default=(datetime.datetime.now))`

because there is not `DateTime` format in SQLite