# Unable to insert date as a string in sqlite3

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to insert date into sqlite3. My date is formatted as a ISO 8601 string. I insert it as a string but somehow sqlite3 recognizes it as a date and prevents insertion
with the following error:

StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.

I am using the pandabase library to convert pandas to Sqlite database tables. In pandas I store the date as a string type but when it gets inserted into sqlite3, it tries to get inserted as a date.

I want to insert it as a normal string.

```
pandabase.to_sql(dataframe, table_name=TABLE_NAME, con=PATH,
                         how="append")
```

How to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344237/error-sqlite-datetime-type-only-accepts-python-datetime-and-date-objects-a

Comment: *ISO 8601 string* != *Python datetime object* -> did you try to pass a datetime object instead of the iso string (e.g. datetime.fromisoformat(s) will give you the dt obj).

Comment: I converted it to a string MrFuppes

Comment: well, the error says a datetime object is expected...

Comment: Actually the database tables are already defined (not by me) and the date is to be inserted as a varchar. That's the reason I am wanting to convert it to a string

Comment: And also, I gave it as a string. Sqlite does have string data type. So instead of taking it as a string it takes it up (a string) as a datetime by default.