# How to use the same code for both sqlite and postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

My sqlalchemy code needs to support both sqlite and postgres, but right now it is not working for sqlite.

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.

I checked [Error - "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python " "datetime and date objects as input."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344237/error-sqlite-datetime-type-only-accepts-python-datetime-and-date-objects-a) but making this change in my entire code base is not possible as it has more than one place where a date string is used instead of datetime

This is my code, it works for postgres engine, but it does not work for sqlite, can I modify anything other than what the above link suggests so my code runs on both sqlite and postgres

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col = Column(DateTime)

engine = create_engine("postgresql://tony:tony@localhost:5432")
# engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(Foo(col='2023-01-07T11:08:31Z'))
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB-API spec expects SQL DATETIME to be provided as python [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters)).

I believe `psycopg2` offers an extenstion that will handle ISO 8601 formatted strings, but this is an extension.

If you want to be most compatible, use `datetime.datetime` object to pass and retrieve dates.

Also why import `DateTime` from `sqlalchemy.types` ? It's available under `sqlalchemy` directly.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col = Column(DateTime)

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres") # OK
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.db") # OK

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(Foo(col=datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-07T11:08:31Z")))
    session.commit()
```

---

If you need compatibility for runtime (not tests), you can use the following [`TypeDecorator`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types).

Look further into the docs if you want more than coercing bind parameters, but this will allow your to input ISO 8601 str in SQLite.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

Base = declarative_base()

class ISO8601DateTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if dialect.name == "sqlite" and isinstance(value, str):
            value = datetime.fromisoformat(value)
        return value

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col = Column(ISO8601DateTime)  # NOTE: decorated type

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres") # OK
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.db") # OK

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(Foo(col=datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-07T11:08:31Z")))
    session.add(Foo(col="2023-01-07T11:08:31Z"))
    session.commit()
```

**NB.** for tests, if unit testing, mock the database adapter, if integration (and higher) testing, [use the same DB as you'll use in production](https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/).

Comment: thank you for your reply and for the import suggestion, while doing `datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-07T11:08:31Z")` makes the code work, as mentioned in my question, there is more than one occurrence where I have this, is there anyway I can monkeypatch or something so I can change in one place and have it reflected?

Comment: What is your use case here ? Unit testing, integration testing or making your program compatible to run on both ?

Comment: the program has to run on both, if you care about the reason, it was decided to not use postgres instances for "free accounts" for cost reasons, so these free accounts will be in an environment where the database would be sqlite

Comment: Alright then you can have a look at my edit about a `TypeDecorator` which parses the ISO 8601 string if a string is passed for datetime in SQLite dialect. But if you have any possibility, I would recomment refactoring to handle datetime as datetime objects.

Comment: thank you so much, I agree with your recommendation for future usecase, right now this is exactly what I wanted to have